# Cannot connect to public wifi on fresh install ubuntu 17.10

Tags: networking, wireless, 17.10

Just installed ubuntu one day ago, wifi works fine in my house. However, whenever I try to go use ubuntu at a library or even starbucks nothing happens when I connect. I'm assuming it has something to do with the authentication of the wifi through browsers? Please someone help I'd rather not have to boot into windows on my super slow laptop.

Comment: What does it mean by 'Nothing happens'? Not even connecting signal?

Comment: @Redbob So I see the wifi under my list of available networks to connect to but when I select connect. I just get a ? at the top right. When I try to go to firefox to try and accept terms and conditions etc like you would on any other device the page never appears and I just get a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

For Starbucks specifically I need to use Firefox to access the login page. The page prompt doesn’t appear on Chrome/Chromium, however on Firefox. 
So connect to the network and then open Firefox, click the prompt to go to the login in page and should be up and running from there.

Comment: The thing is I tried using Firefox but a prompt never came up.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found a solution after smarky mentioned chromium. I went to the starbucks store after downloading to try a different web browser. It didn't work but it gave the response dns-probe-finished-bad-config-error. I did not see this on firefox so i googled it up after and saw a stackoverflow post about this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32045682/dns-probe-finished-bad-config-error

Anyways it suggested you to add nameserver 8.8.8.8 and nameserver 8.8.4.4 to your /etc/resolv.conf that being said i just sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf and added in the appropriate nameservers and a couple seconds later the starbucks terms popped up on my firefox. Anyways thanks to everyone who tried to help. I wouldn't have figured it out if I didn't post this here so ty. If this helps anyone else out hurray!

Answer (score 0):

smarky7cd is on the right track with the "login / prompt" page.
When connecting to a public wifi network like Starbucks or McDonald's, you first need to accept their terms ( or an excuse for ads and such ) or what Mozilla Firefox appropriately calls that network login page.

But I suggest looking at your network card's details and putting the Default Gateway's address directly in your browser's address bar. It works sometimes at some places. It worked at a McDonald's once, also at one shopping center in my city, but it's a good start.

If all fails, try [this address...](https://mcd-e.datavalet.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.html)